# Toggle multiple divs with classes

Tags: html, toggle, hide, show

I need some help:

```
    <button">Text</button>
<div class="show-on-button-click">Content</div>

<button">Text2</button>
<div class="show-on-button-click">Content2</div>

<button">Text3</button>
<div class="show-on-button-click">Content3</div>
```

I´de like to show content when the user clicks on the button. But it wont work, even all divs are shown, or it doesnt open and only the buttons are shown.

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use some JavaScript/Jquery ;-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".show-on-button-click").toggle();
    });
});
```

Hope you solve it !!